# Bind Button.IsEnabled to a property in a TextBox's data source

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a `Foo` class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string IsDirty { get; private set; }
}
```

and I have xaml with a `TextBox` and a `Button` bound to `Foo`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsDirty}" ... />
```

Once the text in the `TextBox` is changed (updated on `KeyDown`), `Foo.IsDirty` becomes true (until a save button is clicked).

Right now, `Button.IsEnabled` is not changing when `Foo.IsDirty` changes.

How might I change the binding on the `Button` so that it becomes enabled as soon as `Foo.IsDirty = true` and vice versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the interface INotifyPropertyChanged in your Foo class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }


private bool _isDirty;

public bool IsDirty { get{ return _isDirty;}
                      private set{
                          _isDirty= value;
                          OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty"); }
                    }
```

Comment: I was worried that might be the problem.  Unfortunately the Foo class extends a class that is part of a framework which I cannot modify (and IsDirty is part of the framework), so if that property isn't notifying I guess I'll have to figure something else out.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not create a class that extends from your base class and `INotifyPropertyChange`, and have `Foo` inherit from that?

Comment: If you can update code of the setter of `Value` property then you can raise `OnPropertyChanged("IsDirty");` there in that setter of `Value` property.